# Dealing with slices concurrently is not working as expected without mutexes

Tags: go, concurrency

Functions `WithMutex` and `WithoutMutex` are giving different results.

`WithoutMutex` implementation is losing values even though I have `Waitgroup` set up.

What could be wrong?

[Do not run on Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_fuR2fIL8u)

***P.S. I am on Windows 10 and Go 1.8.1***

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

var p = fmt.Println

type MuType struct {
    list []int
    *sync.RWMutex
}

var muData *MuType
var data *NonMuType

type NonMuType struct {
    list []int
}

func (data *MuType) add(i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    data.Lock()
    defer data.Unlock()
    data.list = append(data.list, i)
    wg.Done()

}

func (data *MuType) read() []int {
    data.RLock()
    defer data.RUnlock()
    return data.list
}

func (nonmu *NonMuType) add(i int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    nonmu.list = append(nonmu.list, i)
    wg.Done()

}

func (nonmu *NonMuType) read() []int {
    return nonmu.list
}

func WithoutMutex() {
    nonmu := &NonMuType{}
    nonmu.list = make([]int, 0)
    var wg = sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go nonmu.add(i, &wg)

    }
    wg.Wait()
    data = nonmu
    p(data.read())
}

func WithMutex() {
    mtx := &sync.RWMutex{}
    withMu := &MuType{list: make([]int, 0)}
    withMu.RWMutex = mtx
    var wg = sync.WaitGroup{}
    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go withMu.add(i, &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    muData = withMu
    p(muData.read())
}

func stressTestWOMU(max int) {
    p("Without Mutex")
    for ii := 0; ii < max; ii++ {
        WithoutMutex()
    }
}

func stressTest(max int) {
    p("With Mutex")
    for ii := 0; ii < max; ii++ {
        WithMutex()
    }
}

func main() {
    stressTestWOMU(20)
    stressTest(20)
}
```

Comment: I beleive you mean to say `WithoutMutex` is dropping values?

Comment: This does not show on playground because playground uses GOMAXPROCS=1, so nothing is ever truly concurrent.

Comment: My bad, its a typo Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slices are not safe for concurrent writes, so I am in no way surprised that `WithoutMutex` does not appear to be consistent at all, and has dropped items.

The `WithMutex` version consistently has 10 items, but in jumbled orders. This is also to be expected, since the mutex protects it so that only one can append at a time. There is no guarantee as to which goroutine will run in which order though, so it is a race to see which of the rapidly spawned goroutines will get to append first.

The waitgroup does not do anything to control access or enforce ordering. It merely provides a signal at the end that everything is done.

Comment: Waitgroup is used to wait until all goroutines are finished. Ordering is irrelevant to me. So howcome values are dropped while I have waitgroup active? Kinda perplexed

Comment: Because you have 10 different goroutines all trying to append at the same time. That involves expanding the underlying array and copying data around. If you don't use a mutex to make sure only one at a time can do it, some of their changes are going to conflict and get lost.

Comment: Waitgroup waits until all goroutines are finished, but it does nothing to coordinate them or ensure they play nicely together before they are done.

Comment: Ahh, make sense now. As you said slices are not concurrent safe, multiple goroutines can mess up. Thanks